# Unverified breakpoint (Breakpoint is set but not yet bound)

Tags: angular, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron

I had been successfully debugging my angular app in Chrome via Chrome Debugger extension with automatic created settings. But [something] happened, and after one of my Windows 7 reboots I got unactive breakpoints. I suppose that it was affected by Windows PATH environment variable change. Why I thinking so? I got a message like "PATH has a bad value, do you want to fix it?" when Windows started. Unfortunately I can't reproduce my old PATH value. It can be a coincidence, but after this case debugging does not work.

[image: Breakpoints issue]
[image: Breakpoints issue]

No matter where a breakpoints are set: neither in the beginning of function or code block, nor in the middle of block, nor in a variable declaration, nor a variable operations. Breakpoints is not activated in noone of angular components: neither root component, nor others.

I use Google Chrome latest version.
Interestingly, I installed the Debugger for Electron extension, which also starts up successfully, but the breakpoints are still not activated.

Other info:

[image: Angular versions]

launch.json:

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [       
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "trace": true,
            "sourceMaps": true,
        },
        {
            "type": "electron",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Electron",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "appDir": "H:/opened-in-VSCode-folder",
        },
    ]
}
```

Project folder structure:

[image: Project structure]

In launch.json also not works:

- changing "webRoot" to "${workspaceFolder}/src", "${workspaceFolder}\\src", "${workspaceFolder}/dist" and a lot of others variants.
- disabling or enabling "trace": true
- disabling or enabling "sourceMaps": true

Additional reboots of Chrome, Windows, VSCode, reinstalling Angular and Electron don't leads to success. Antivirus stopped. Windows "Last successful login" did not help.

Thanks for any info.

**UPD 1:**
The only word "error" in the vscode-chrome-debug.txt log file:

```
... 
  {"id":5,"result":{}} [09:54:38.267 UTC] ← From target:
  {"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"'Runtime.run' wasn't found"},"id":6}
  [09:54:38.267 UTC] ← From target:
  ...
```

**UPD 2:**
Reinstalling windows not helped too. I guess the problem in the packages versions.

Comment: I had tried with electron debugger but getting same error

Comment: @MayankVadiya what versions of software are you using? See my answer below

Comment: Version : 1.38.1, Chrome : 69.0.3497.128,Node : 10.11.0, V8: 6.9.427.31

Comment: @MayankVadiya ok it's really strange stuff. what does your vscode-chrome-debug.txt log file say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating some software:

- VS Code: 1.37.1
- Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
- Node.js: 10.11.0
- V8: 6.9.427.31

Answer (score 14):

For me was problem in another.
When you are added *launch.json*, you can see **webRoot** variable that has a value **${workspaceFolder}** by default.
Lets check what does it mean in this [source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

> ${workspaceFolder} - the path of the folder opened in VS Code

and in my case angular project was inside folder of another project and when i tried to debug i get *breakpoint is set but not yet bound* message.

[image: Note: **angular** folder not opened as root folder]

And if you will open your angular project in VSCode explorer as root folder, your breakpoints will work.

[image]

Or if you don't want to open separate folder in VS Code explorer, you can specify in *launch.json* path to angular folder, like: ***${workspaceFolder}/folder/folder/...***

After this changes your debug should work.

Comment: Wow, you saved me a bit of time, and we're only a week apart from each other in running into this problem. Glad you took the hit, @llotall -- and thanks for posting your solution!

Comment: I've been trying to solve this for days now. Thank you very much for pointing this out. Multiple projects in one vs code workspace is always asking for issues I've noticed. Thanks man, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

After verifying my `launch.json` contents (as mentioned by @llotall and in several other places), I stopped and restarted VSCode (Chrome was already shutdown).

This fixed the problem for me.